# R, tmap, animation_tmap, ImageMagick

Tags: r, animation, imagemagick, tmap

I'm getting this error while using animation_tmap, although ImageMagick is installed and path is added in the Windows environment settings.

Error in animation_tmap(tmCO2, filename = "animationCO2.gif", delay = 60) : 
Could not find ImageMagick. Make sure it is installed and included in the systems PATH
In addition: Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c convert -version' had status 4 
2: In syscall("convert -version") :
'convert -version' execution failed with error code 4

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Are you able to execute the ImageMagick command `convert` in your command line? I believe there is a Windows system tool also called convert, so that may be the issue.

Comment: I didn't find any executable convert file in ImageMagick folder. Yes there is a convert tool in Windows. Any solution for this? thanks

Comment: It' solved..I had to opt to add convert.exe separately during installation of IM.. thanks!

Comment: my new problem is the gif saves as a fixed image and not an animation. solution appreciated

Comment: Please open a new question regarding your animation problem with a reproducible example to get more help.

Comment: Could you post how to have created tmCO2?

Comment: @MartijnTennekes
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(tmap)

worldshp <- shapefile("countries.shp")
CO2data <- read.csv("CO2.csv")
CO2shp <- merge(worldshp,CO2data,by = "ISO3", type = "FULL")
shapefile(CO2shp, "CO2shp.shp", overwrite = TRUE)

tmCO2 <- tm_shape(CO2shp) +tm_fill(c("X1995_.YR1995.","X1996_.YR1996.","X1997_.YR1997.","X1998_.YR1998.","X1999_.YR1999.","X2000_.YR2000.","X2001_.YR2001.","X2002_.YR2002.","X2003_.YR2003."), style="kmeans", n=10, title="CO2 - 1995 metric tons per capita")

animation_tmap(tmCO2, filename = "animationCO2.mpg",delay=60)

Comment: You probably see one plot with small multiples? You'll need to add  `+ tm_facets(nrow=1, ncol=1)`

Comment: Yes, that's right. tried tm_facets, and get the error - Error: Fill argument neither colors nor valid variable name(s)

Comment: found a solution with another package choropleth..thanks @MartijnTennekes!